# How to integrate(maths, physics) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, physics

I am creating a simulation of earth and a satellite in orbit and trying to make it follow the rules of physics but don't know how to integrate the various variables with respect to time. I tried something but feel like it is wrong. The complete code is large so some part of it is:

```
tend=time.time()  
startTime=time.time()

#loop starts here
t = time.time() - tend
r = (x**(2) + y**(2))**(1/2)

if r>6371000:
    g = -((6.67408*10**(-11))*(5.972*10**(24)))/(r**(2))
else:
    g = -((6.67408*10**(-11))*(5.972*10**(24))*r)/((6371000)**(3))

gx = g*x/r
gy = g*y/r
vx += gx*t
vy += gy*t
x += vx*t
y += vy*t

tend=time.time()
```

So basically what i did is take the dt element (usually taken in physics) to be equal to the time taken in processing one loop of my code. Also, this is a graphical simulation in pygame but if you believe that there is some other module that can do the display job better than please tell.

Comment: There are ready-made integrators in the `scipy.integrate` module. Also you should scale your numbers with scales such that most of your numbers are roughly 1 (scale sizes by astronomic units, etc.). You can reduce numerical errors this way.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by scaling numbers?

Comment: Instead of `r` in kilometers keep track of `r` in Earth radius units. Then when you're done with 1 million time steps (and 1 million floating-point errors), you can take your final result and multiply it with the Earth's radius to obtain a physically relevant result. Similarly if there's a meaningful time scale, use those instead of seconds or whatever.

Comment: Oh okay. That's a great idea

Comment: @AndrasDeak: No, the numerical errors are independent of the scale that you compute in, esp. for fixed-step solvers. But more advanced solvers that target some error size automatically, for instance with adaptive time steps, have norm computations and some heuristic part in them, and that is calibrated for problems where all state components have the same scale and that scale is inside some reasonable range, say 1e-3 to 1e6.

Comment: @LutzL either the error depends on the scale or we're missing each other's point. With `r = 6371000` compare `sum([r*0.1, r*0.2, -r*0.3])` with `sum([0.1, 0.2, -0.3])*r`: this theoretically zero number assumes two very different values depending on how you scale your data before summation. Perhaps the confusion is here: when I say "numerical error" I don't mean errors in the ODE discretization, but rather floating-point errors that accumulate over a lot of time steps. The epsilon can become relatively large if your doubles are not close to 1.

Comment: My point is that if you take `[0.5, 0.25, 0.125]` as factors, then there should be no difference. The difference you observe is within the error of about `(|r|+1)*mu` of multiplication and addition, that two equivalent expressions can have slightly different errors is to be expected. If the scale factor is not a power of 2 then the scaling transformation forward and backward might introduce additional errors, this is to be balanced with the reduced errors of a properly working integration controller.